# I can't import my Geth account, where do I get the 64 hex character while my UTC file shows only the mac I've loaded and it said too short

Tags: import, keystore

please give a solution. I can't Import my geth account.

It said:
***C:\Windows\system32>geth account import --datadir value 092426c0333f315bd569f279d********
***Fatal: Failed to load the private key: key file too short, want 64 hex characters***

Answer (score 0):

Create a new account:

```sh
geth account new
```

Then, replace the content of file created in ./ethereum/keystore/ with your json file and the publick key in file name (the las part of --)